# Owl Carousel 2 beta 3 and Knockout 3.3

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, owl-carousel

I am trying to develop a dynamic carousel with data coming from a knockout observable array.

There's a few problems with the result.

- The carousel doesn't show up at all, instead, all of the owl-item has an active class and it shows on the page.
- The other problem is that none of the dots or buttons are showing.

What I am trying to accomplish is to add or remove items to myItems collection and have the carousel update automatically on the UI

I am using knockout 3.3, foundation zurb 5, jQuery 2.1.4

knockout custom binding handler

```
(function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["knockout", "jquery", "jquery.ui.sortable"], factory);
  } else {
    factory(window.ko, jQuery);
  }
})(function (ko, $, undefined) {
  /**
   * Helper function that refreshes the items of the given owl instance.
   *
   * @param {{ $owlWrapper: jQuery, $owlItems: jQuery, $userItems: jQuery, itemsAmount: number }} owl
   *          The owl carousel instance that should be refreshed
   */
  var refreshOwl = function (owl) {
    // find all owl items that are currently wrapped in the owl wrapper element
    owl.$owlItems = owl.$stage.children(".owl-item");

    // extract the elements that are wrapped in the owl items
    owl.$userItems = owl.$owlItems.children();
    owl.itemsAmount = owl.$userItems.length;

    // TODO: check if items have been removed and adjust owl's internal current position
    owl.refresh();

  };

  /**
   * Helper function for creating an options object that can be passed to ko.bindingHandlers.template.init as a value for
   * the 'valueAccessor' parameter.
   *
   * @param {{data: *, as: string, afterRender: function, afterAdd: function, beforeRemove: function}} options
   * @param {function} afterRender
   * @returns {{foreach: *, as: string, afterRender: function, afterAdd: function, beforeRemove: function}}
   */
  var makeTemplateBindingOptions = function (options, afterRender) {
    var templateOptions = {
      foreach: options.data,
      as: options.as,
      afterRender: afterRender,
      afterAdd: options.afterAdd,
      beforeRemove: options.beforeRemove
    };

    if (options.afterRender) {
      var userAfterRender = options.afterRender;

      templateOptions.afterRender = function (element, data) {
        if (afterRender) {
          afterRender.call(data, element, data);
        }

        userAfterRender(data, element, data);
      };
    }

    return templateOptions;
  };

  ko.bindingHandlers.owlCarousel = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      // the options that have been configured with the owlCarousel binding
      var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

      // the bound element as a jQuery object
      var $elem = $(element);

      // initialize owl carousel
      var owlOptions = options.owlOptions || {};
      $elem.owlCarousel(owlOptions);

      // the owl instance that has just been created
      var owl = $elem.data("owl.carousel"); // $elem.data("owlCarousel");

      // register a callback that is being executed when the element is removed
      // in that case the carousel is no longer required and can be destroyed
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        if (owl) {
          owl.destroy();
        }
      });

      // create options for the template binding with a afterRender event hook
      // that causes the carousel to refresh its internal state
      var templateOptions = makeTemplateBindingOptions(options, function () {
        refreshOwl(owl);
      });

      return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init(owl.$stage[0], function () { return templateOptions; }, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      // the options that have been configured with the owlCarousel binding
      var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

      // the bound element as a jQuery object
      var $elem = $(element);

      // the owl instance that has been associated with the element
      var owl = $elem.data("owl.carousel");

      // create options for the template binding with a afterRender event hook
      // that causes the carousel to refresh its internal state
      var templateOptions = makeTemplateBindingOptions(options, function (element, data) {
        refreshOwl(owl);
      });

      ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(owl.$stage[0], function () { return templateOptions; }, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
  };
});
```

javascript code to bind with the view

```
  var myItems = ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'Image 1', url: "http://placehold.it/150x200&text=book cover1" },
    { name: 'Image 2', url: "http://placehold.it/150x200&text=book cover2" },
    { name: 'Image 3', url: "http://placehold.it/150x200&text=book cover3" },
    { name: 'Image 4', url: "http://placehold.it/150x200&text=book cover4" },
    { name: 'Image 5', url: "http://placehold.it/150x200&text=book cover5" },
    { name: 'Image 6', url: "http://placehold.it/150x200&text=book cover6" },
    { name: 'Image 7', url: "http://placehold.it/150x200&text=book cover7" },
    { name: 'Image 8', url: "http://placehold.it/150x200&text=book cover8" }
  ]);
```

HTML:

```
      <div id="myCarousel"
           class="owl-carousel owl-theme book-slide large-11 large-centered columns"
           data-bind="owlCarousel: { data: myItems, owlOptions: { items: 3 } }">

        <img data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }" />

      </div>
```

HTML output:

```
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme book-slide large-11 large-centered columns owl-loaded owl-drag" id="myCarousel" data-bind="owlCarousel: { data: myItems, owlOptions: { responsive:{ 0:{ items:2}, 600:{items:3}, 1000:{items:5}} } }">
<div class="owl-stage-outer">
  <div class="owl-stage" style="transition:all; width: 1016px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 203.2px;">
      <img title="Image 1" alt="Image 1" src="http://placehold.it/150x200&amp;text=book cover1" data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 203.2px;">
      <img title="Image 2" alt="Image 2" src="http://placehold.it/150x200&amp;text=book cover2" data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 203.2px;">
      <img title="Image 3" alt="Image 3" src="http://placehold.it/150x200&amp;text=book cover3" data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 203.2px;">
      <img title="Image 4" alt="Image 4" src="http://placehold.it/150x200&amp;text=book cover4" data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 203.2px;">
      <img title="Image 5" alt="Image 5" src="http://placehold.it/150x200&amp;text=book cover5" data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 203.2px;">
      <img title="Image 6" alt="Image 6" src="http://placehold.it/150x200&amp;text=book cover6" data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 203.2px;">
      <img title="Image 7" alt="Image 7" src="http://placehold.it/150x200&amp;text=book cover7" data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 203.2px;">
      <img title="Image 8" alt="Image 8" src="http://placehold.it/150x200&amp;text=book cover8" data-bind="attr: { src: url, title: name, alt: name }">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-nav disabled">
  <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
  <div class="owl-next">next</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-dots disabled">
  <div class="owl-dot active">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?